# Huile et eau, l'huile et l'eau ?

Tags: articles, conjonctions, coordination, énumération

J'ai un problème avec la phrase « Huile et eau ne se mélangent pas ». Est-ce qu'il faut dire « L'huile et l'eau ne se mélangent pas » ? Mon sentiment est que le premier est plus générique, et ce que j'ai vu sur les articles parle de noms virtuels qui ne sont pas instanciés par un article, mais j'ai comme un doute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J'ai passé en revue les neufs cas que Grevisse donne où on omet l'article devant des noms communs.  Deux me semblent pertinents ici (le premier plus que le second d'ailleurs), sans qu'aucun n'apporte une nuance sémantique ni n'interdise l'utilisation de l'article :

> - l'article est souvent absent dans le style proverbial (proverbes, comparaisons et autres expressions traditionnelles et sentencieuses). [exemples omis]
> - l'article est assez souvent absent dans les énumérations, ce qui donne plus de vivacité à l'expression. [exemples omis] La langue littéraire construit aussi les noms sans déterminants dans des coordinations à deux termes [exemples omis]

Answer (score 1):

> Huile et eau ne se mélangent pas.

C'est un principe, un axiome comme en géométrie : « Deux droites ayant un et un seul point commun sont dites sécantes ». La phrase se suffit à elle-même.

Il y a aussi un effet de contraction de texte, avec suppression des mots inutiles, dont le Droit français est friand : « Tout condamné à mort aura la tête tranchée » et non pas « Tous *les* condamnés ... », ici condamné ne signifie pas une personne mais un statut juridique (article supprimé depuis 1981 année de l'abolition de la peine de mort en France).

> L'huile et l'eau ne se mélangent pas ...

C'est un constat que l'on relate ou que l'on réalise dans une expérience. Les `...` indiquent que l'on va préciser un des contextes dans lequel l'expérience est vérifiée.

---

*Précision suite au commentaire*

*Huile* et *eau* sont des entrées de dictionnaire, elles sont définies sans article.
Il faut donc lire : « [La substance] *huile* et [la substance] *eau* ne se mélangent pas. », ou « quel que soit la nature de ***l**’huile* et la nature de ***l**’eau*, ces substances ne se mélangent pas », dans ce deuxième exemple on est obligé d’ajouter l’article pour définir la particularité d’une huile ou d’une eau.

Avec article : « L'[objet]huile et l'[objet] eau ne se mélangent pas … » huile et eau sont des portions quantifiables et particulières et donc définies par un article.

---

*Précision suite à une recherche sur [Omission de l'article](http://www.synapse-fr.com/manuels/ART_OMIS.htm)*

La dernière ligne des exemples peut convenir si l'on accepte que  *huile et eau* sont  « des noms qui se désignent eux-mêmes » ou qu'une *formule* est  « l'inscription »   résultant d'une expérience :

> – devant les noms qui se désignent eux-mêmes et dans les inscriptions :
>
> - Axe vient du latin « axis » et signifie proprement « essieu ».
> - Voiture à vendre.

Comment: Je ne perçois pas du tout cette nuance.  Quelqu'un aurait-il des références la décrivant plus en détail? Je n'ai pas l'impression que ces phrases sont substituables, mais je suis incapable de dire s'il y a une nuance de sens, ou simplement des différences de style et de niveau de langage rendant l'une ou l'autre plus appropriée suivant le contexte.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Suite à votre commentaire, j'ai complété ma réponse.

Comment: Il n'y a certainement pas autonymie ici (ce sont les matières qui sont non-miscibles) ni dans _voiture à vendre_ (ce qui est à vendre c'est l'objet; Grevisse place ce cas dans les phrases averbales, il a _maison à vendre_ comme exemple)

Answer (score 0):

Même si j'aurais cru qu'il fallait dire *l’huile et l’eau* dans tous les cas (je ne saurais même pas comment dire *et eau*, soit sans [eh oh?] ou avec [eh toh?] liaison), je vois bien maintenant que les 2 phrases sont employées couramment, avec une préférence, d’après « N-grams », pour [*L’huile et l’eau*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=l%27huile%20et%20l%27eau%2Chuile%20et%20eau&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cl%27%20huile%20et%20l%27%20eau%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chuile%20et%20eau%3B%2Cc0). (Desolé et je ne sais pas pourquoi, mais il semble qu'il faut (re)clicker sur le bouton bleu ("chercher bcp de livres") une fois rendu au site pour avoir les résultats.)

Je ne suis pas assez compétent en "N-gram" pour savoir comment déterminer si chaque phrase a son propre usage et nuance, mais en "googlant" ["l’huile et l’eau"](https://www.google.com/search?q=oil%20and%20water%20don%27t%20mix%20expression%20%22l%27huile%20et%20l%27eau%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb#rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&q=%22l%27huile%20et%20l%27eau%22) et puis ["huile et eau"](https://www.google.com/search?q=oil%20and%20water%20don%27t%20mix%20expression%20%22l%27huile%20et%20l%27eau%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb#q=%22huile%20et%20eau%22&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&start=0), j'ai eu un peu près 334,000 résultats pour le premier et 101,000 résultats pour le second, qui confirme, au moins, ce que "N-gram" dit (mais toujours sans bénéfice de contexte).

Mais en regardant parmi quelques pages de ces 323,000 et 101,000 résultats, j'ai vu beaucoup d'exemple des deux contextes principaux desdites deux phrases (comme idiome et comme constat scientifique) parmi chacune des 2 listes des résultats, qui me font croire que les deux phrases sont très souvent employées comme si elles sont interchangeable sans regard du contexte.

Bien entendu, l'usage ample ne fait pas forcement l'usage correcte, et donc peut-être les nuances existent, mais je ne les ai pas trouvées avec mes soi-disant "recherches."